# Java parse a 8601 formatted string to a more readable date parse error

Tags: java, date, datetime, iso8601

I'm getting dates and trying to parse them into more readable dates but I keep getting a parse error, the formatting looks correct to me but its not working

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
 DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        Date date1 = df.parse(purchase.getRedeem_at());

        String readableDate = df2.format(date1);

        b.append(readableDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

An example string im trying to parse is

```
2014-08-12T02:30:00Z
```

Comment: `02:30:00Z`vs `HH:mm'Z'` Should I vote to close as a typo?

Comment: well it wasn't a typo it was an incorrent parsing format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the seconds part from your first format string.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
//                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 2):

joda will [parse this format](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) right out of the box:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime ourDate = fmt.parseDateTime(jdkDate);
```

If you have further problems, do leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should add "ss"

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```